# Kepler vs Indigo for Apache Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have been told that I should use Kepler with apache tomcat . 
However, I am using Indigo and do not have any problems .

Should I switch the project to Kepler ? 
What are the advantages of having it with Kepler as opposed to Indigo ?

Comment: first, let me tell you that your movies are great, mr Borat :-) I am using Indigo for years and it works. From Juno, eclipse foundation lost a lot of developers (I think because oracle bought sun and java, so some companies decided to invest in something else, I don't know) and then they released a very bad release. I really hope Kepler is better this time, but since Juno, I have to say that many developers have lost their faith.

Comment: for those who remember http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/09/eclipse-juno-performance

Answer (score 2):

While I can't comment on the specifics of the tomcat container in Indigo vs Kepler, there has been a wide range of improvements across the board for the Kepler release. I personally switched to Kepler from Indigo when it was released last year and find it pleasant to use, which was the opposite with the Juno release.

Some of the improvements include but are not limited to:

- Greater support for NoSQL databases
- Improved Git integration
- Improvements to Linux Tools and Java Development Tools
- New m2e connectors for JavaEE and WTP
- Overall platform improvements; Juno problems have been addressed

I know I haven't addressed the tomcat question with facts but I can say that I personally found it easier to deploy Tomcat applications in Kepler than Indigo and I noticed less errors on start-up.

[Source](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/06/26/top-10-eclipse-kepler-features/)